# JavaScript - Function that Splits String into Words, Identifies Word With The Most Vowels - Using For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, split

I've checked some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063011/word-with-the-most-vowels) but I don't feel like the answers apply directly to what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to find the word with the most vowels in a given string. I know how to split a string into words like this:

`let words = string.split(" ");`

And so far I have:

```js
function mostVowels(string) {

  let vowels = ["aeiouAEIOU"];
  let words = string.split(" ");

  //initiate vowel count at 0

  let counter = 0;

  //loop through words

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    //if there are vowels in the word, add vowels to counter
    if (vowels.includes(i)) {
      counter++
    }
  }
  return counter;
}

console.log(mostVowels("I went to the park today."));
```

So obviously I'm pretty far from reaching a solution.

Right now this is returning `0`.

There's 1 vowel in each of the first five words in that string, and there are two vowels in "today", so ultimately we want for this function to return "today" as the word with the most vowels.

At this point I'm just trying to get a vowel count for the first word in the string - it should be `1`.

Then I figure I'll be able to compare the counts of the different words to determine which count is the greatest.

Comment: Have a think through what you are doing. You find the individual words perfectly, but now you need to check each char 9f the and see if that is a vowel

Comment: Your current logic check if vowels includes the word, which it probably doesn't, unless the word is "a"

Comment: @Leon Rather the code checks if `vowels` includes `i` ..?

Comment: @teemu yeah! Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `vowels` to be an *array of characters*, rather than an array containing a single string. Then, inside the loop over `words`, initialize the counter to 0, and iterate over each *character* in the word. If the character is included in the vowels array, increment the counter. At the end of iterating over the word, if the counter for this word is better than the best counter so far, assign the counter and the word to outer variables, indicating the best word / counter so far. At the end  of the function, return the best word:

```js
function mostVowels(string) {

  let vowels = [..."aeiouAEIOU"];
  let words = string.split(" ");

  let bestCounter = 0;
  let bestWord;
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const word = words[i];
    //initiate vowel count at 0
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      const char = word[i];
      //if there are vowels in the word, add vowels to counter
      if (vowels.includes(char)) {
        counter++
      }
    }
    // finished iterating through loop,
    // now check to see if it's better than the best word so far:
    if (counter > bestCounter) {
      bestCounter = counter;
      bestWord = word;
    }
  }
  return bestWord;
}

console.log(mostVowels("I went to the park today."));
console.log(mostVowels("I went to the fooaeuiubar park today."));
```

Or, perhaps more elegantly, using array methods instead:

```js
const vowels = [..."aeiouAEIOU"];
const getVowelCount = word => [...word].reduce((a, char) => a + Boolean(vowels.includes(char)), 0);
function mostVowels(string) {
  let bestCounter = 0;
  return string.split(' ')
    .reduce((bestWordSoFar, thisWord) => {
      const thisVowelCount = getVowelCount(thisWord);
      if (thisVowelCount > bestCounter) {
        bestCounter = thisVowelCount;
        return thisWord;
      } else {
        return bestWordSoFar;
      }
    });
}

console.log(mostVowels("I went to the park today."));
console.log(mostVowels("I went to the fooaeuiubar park today."));
```

Comment: Yep, extracting them into variables like that isn't *necessary*, but it significantly improves readability when you do it at the top of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to approach this through map-reduce trying to keep things pure and clean. But I had to set `mostVowels` in reduce, making it a bit stupid.

But here's my shot:

```js
const handleSentence = (sentence = '') => {
  const vowels = /[a|e|i|o|u]+/gi;
  const words = sentence.split(' ');
  let mostVowels = '';
  
  const getVowels = (str = '') => {
    try {
      return str.match(vowels).join('').length
    } catch (err) {
      return 0;
    }
  };

  const getMostVowels = (a, b, i) => {
    if (a < b) {
      mostVowels = words[i];
      return b;
    }
  
    return a;
  }
  
  words.map(getVowels).reduce(getMostVowels);
  return mostVowels;
}

console.log(handleSentence('this is an example string for demonstrating the function'));

console.log(handleSentence('yet another example of the effectiveness of function'));

console.log(handleSentence('gypsy rhythm'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. A quick question - how would you account for when there are not any vowels in any of the words? If there are no vowels, the function should return an empty string `" "`.

Comment: I tried to add `if (words.includes != vowels) {return " ";}` before the last return and this did not work.

Comment: @HappyHands31 I updated the code with **try catch** block and comparison which would return empty string set on line: `let mostVowels = '';`

Answer (score 1):

One alternate is to use `regex`

```js
let mostVowels = (input) =>{
  let max = 0;
  let splited = input.split(' ')
  splited.forEach((e, index) => {
    let count = (e.match(/[aeiou]/gi)||[]).length
    max = count > max ? index : max
  })
  return splited[max]
}

console.log(mostVowels("I went to the park today."));
console.log(mostVowels("I went to the fooaeuiubar park today. xyz"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter alternative with sorting :

```js
const vowels = s => s.split(/[aeiou]/i).length - 1; 

const mostVowels = s => s.split(/\W/).sort((a, b) => vowels(b) - vowels(a))[0];

console.log( mostVowels("I went to the park today.") );
```

and without sorting :

```js
const vowels = s => s.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi, '').length;

const mostVowels = s => s.split(/\W/).reduce((a, b) => vowels(a) > vowels(b) ? a : b);

console.log( mostVowels("I went to the park today.") );
```